# I can't import cookies directly into server actions in Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a Next JS 13 project and I encountered an issue with server actions. Server actions can be used directly on form or button components, however, in my personal experience I found that you are most likely to define a server component in a separate file and import it into your client components. This works great until you want to access cookies or headers. If you try calling the `headers()` or `cookies()` function from `next/headers` you get the following error: `Error: Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available`. This only happens if the server action is in a separate file eg.

actions.js

```
"use server"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export default async function myFunction() {
   const token = cookies().get("my-token")
   return "done"
}
```

app/page.jsx

```
"use client"
import myFunction from "@/actions.js"

export default function Page() {
   async function doSomething() {
      await myFunction()
   }

   return <button onClick={doSomething}>my button</button>
}
```

Trying to run the following code resulted in the error above. I found a workaround which is posted as an answer below. Does anyone have an alternative solution that is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v13.4.6, this bug has been fixed. In order to update to a newer version of Next JS refer to this page: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-13.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I implemented.

actions.js

```
"use server"

export default async function myFunction(cookies) {
   const token = await cookies.get("my-token")
   return "done"
}
```

app/layout.jsx

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export default async function RootLayout({ children, params }) {
   
  params.cookies = {
    get: async function(cookie) {
      "use server"
      return cookies().get(cookie)
    },
    set: async function(cookie) {
      "use server"
      return cookies().set(cookie)
    }
  }

  return children
}
```

app/page.jsx

```
"use client"
import myFunction from "@/actions.js"

export default function Page({ params: { cookies }}) {
   async function doSomething() {
      await myFunction(cookies)
   }

   return <button onClick={doSomething}>my button</button>
}
```

A similar thing can be done for `headers`.